# Render Layers Shadows

Tags: render-layers, layers, viewlayers

I have two render layers: SCENE & OBJECTS and I want to render them separately and combine them in the compositor.

Why I don't have the shadows from the objects (in the foreground) layer interacting (casted) onto the scene layer (background)?

FILE:
[image]

Comment: Hello, how could you have the shadow if they are into 2 separate view layers? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @moonboots I am learning about render layers...for large scenes to render objects on different layers. So, is it possible?

Comment: What is possible exactly? Please define the final result you want. If the cube is in a different layer than the floor, it can't cast any shadow on it by definition

Comment: @moonboots I assume that one of the purposes of render layers is to break large (large memory) scene into layers so that you render those layers separately and combine them afterwards. If that is not the case, then what is the purpose of render layers?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: No, render layers are made for example to give different effects to different objects, it doesn't save memory, on the contrary

Comment: @moonboots Correct me if I am wrong, but I ran some render examples and came to the following conclusion: for objects that don't interact with eachother you can reduce the memory required to render by rendering their layers separatelly compared to if you would render them on one single layer. However, for objects that do interact with eachother (direct shadows) you need to render them on single layer or use holdout, which doesn't reduce the memory required to render?

Comment: Sure, if you use Cycles it will be faster to calculate if the objects don't interact, as Blender won't have to take all the indirect lights into account, but for example you'd better play with the Render panel > Light Paths parameters, and also if you use layers you'll lose the shadows for example. I may be wrong but imho View Layers are generally not use for the kind of purpose you're describing

Comment: I also need this. I think I understand exactly what OP wants: to have 2 images rendered separately, for example of an object and its background, but so that the background renders with shadows from the object (as well other light interactions such as glossy reflection). I am also looking for a way to do this with View/Render layers.